# Best Practice for Queuing Activities

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Am currently working on an Xamarin Form application, which requires me to interact with a Web API. There are, however times, when the call may fail, due to internet connectivity or server breaks down. In such situations, I would like to put the data that needs to be send in a queue, and try later on.

I was able to put in a queue, however, my question is, how I can run some kind of timers so that I can keep trying the API at regular interval for the ones in queue. Could someone guide me in understanding what is the best practice in such scenarios ?

Thanks

Comment: You could use [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is there any better solution that timer ? As in, correct me if am wrong, isn't timers traditionally memory hungry?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement this yourself there is a [Library](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) for that.

Especially take a look at the [Retry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry) keyword.

Comment: Hi Thanks Marius. A quick question, can this work if the user navigates away from the page ?